# OpenGL interface - background texture/image

Tags: opengl, glut

I am currently developing a game similar to "Who wants to be a billionaire", the type of game where you are asked a question and you are given several answers from which you have to choose. I designed a background picture in Photoshop that has a "screen" for the question and another 4 "buttons" for the answers.

I am wondering how I could use the image as a window background and be able to click on those "buttons" I designed in Photoshop.

What do you suggest? Which would be the best approach?

Comment: See: http://nehe.gamedev.net/ for a great set of tutorials to get you started. See for example http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/

Comment: This shows me how to set the image as a background but how can I make the buttons in the picture behave like buttons?

Comment: OpenGl does not provide things like buttons. It just allows you to draw the button. Then you need to capture the mouse event - you could use OpenGl `picking` to tell you a mouse event is in a given image. See: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/picking_alpha_blending_alpha_testing_sorting/16005/. But its your problem to shade and animate the button.

Comment: @Keith: Please don't recommend NeHe today. Those tutorials are completely outdated. To bad you can't downvote comments on StackOverflow.

Comment: @datenwolf OK, fair enough (although as a basic intro to concepts I think it has some value). But I'd like to know as comprehensive a resource which _is_ up to date. Can you recommend?

Comment: @Keith: http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could use the image as a window background and be able to click on those "buttons" I designed in Photoshop.

By programming this behavior. OpenGL is not a application framework/toolkit. If you want something to react to a click you have to implement that behavior yourself and draw it the way you want to it. OpenGL gives you pencils, canvas, brushes, but you have to do the art yourself.

Comment: It's not the art I am worried about, it's the behavior of the mouse, so should I just select for example a rectangle area where the click should act as a button?

Comment: I want the bits of the picture act as buttons, for example if I use the screenshot of the desktop as a background image for my window, I would like to make the Start button act like a button, would I have to draw an area that defines the perimeter where the clicks of the mouse have a particular action?

Comment: @Contourette.: OpenGL doesn't deal with user input. It just *draws* things. User input is completely outside the scope of OpenGL. Heck OpenGL doesn't even have the concept of a scene or geometrical objects. GLUT is a framework (GLUT is not part of OpenGL!) which allows you to receive user input (glutMouseFunc, glutMotionFunc, glutPassiveMotionFunc, etc.), but the semantics how user input translates to what's visible must be programmed by **YOU**.